# Add a new data type in monetdb?

Tags: database, types, monetdb

I want to add a new custom data type into monetdb. Do you know the procedure?
I have tried to add it using the gdk_atoms.c but with no luck.

Comment: Is something like this what you're looking for? https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/Userdefinedtypes